# How do I make my toggable divs fade in?

Tags: html, time, onclick, each, fade

I have a small system where you can click on a link, and a div will fade in, you click the link again, and a div will fade in. Until there are 3 divs. This code works fine, but the only thing I'm wondering is to also make each one fade in when you click for each one. Here is my code.

CSS

```
.box {
background-color: #036;
height: 190px;
width: 100px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="News" style="display:none;">
<div class="box" id="news4"></div>
</div>

<div class="News" style="display:none;">
<div class="box" id="news5"></div>
</div>

<span><a href="#" id="add">More news</a></span>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#add').click(function () {
$('.News').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
        return false;
    }
});
var i = 0;
$('.News').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
        i++;
    }
});

if (i == 3) $('#add').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple really. My call function when you press the #add is set too if this css style is set to position, change it from none, to display block. You simple need to change the function from going to none, to having it fade in. Here is the revised code.

BEFORE

```
if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
$(this).css('display', 'block');
```

AFTER

```
if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
$(this).fadeIn( "slow" );
```

Answered my own question... Sigh